# Customise Maximize button on Mac

Tags: osx, window-manager

I am looking for a plugin which can help me do something like following

[image: The Maximize button of a window opens a menu which offers different options for window sizes]

I found a plugin called [SizeWell](http://sizewellplugin.com/) but it has more than what I may need. I am just looking a simple plugin which does the same as above in the above pic.

My operating system is Mac OS X - Yosemite - V 10.10.5.

Comment: How much simpler? If like most of us you just want the old maximise functionality back (rather than this new-fangled fullscreen) you can just ctrl+click (or option+click, or something) on the maximise button.

Comment: @JonStory : I want the different options like `right half screen`, `left half screen`, `full screen`, `top half` and `bottom half`.